# Ask for confirmation before extension update via update server

Tags: joomla-3.x, update

We are implementing an update server feature for our custom Joomla extension.

Is it possible to add confirmation text after selecting the extension and require the click of the update button before connecting to the update server?

For example, I want to show a message like:

> Are you sure you want to update? By clicking the OK button, you agree to our terms and conditions.

After hitting OK, the update server should get connected and the update should be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible using Joomla's standard update server. There could possibly be a way to achieve this, however it's so long winded and I'm not 100% sure it would work, therefore I won't suggest anything.

You basically have 2 choices:

1. You add the Terms and Conditions on the download page on your site for your extension and have the user agree to them.
2. You can do what NoNumber does have have your own Update Manager, which would take some serious time

Comment: cant this be done using `onInstallerBeforePackageDownload`?

Comment: Ah, was not aware on this event. Joomla Docs seriously need to be updated :/